# Separa ruta de archivo con php

Tags: php

Buenas mi problema es que quiero separar una ruta así "C:\xampp\htdocs\Dranix\vista\users\prs\registroCode.php"
y contener cada parte en un array así $ruta[1]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Eh usado $realPath = realpath($ruta);
  $pathParts = pathinfo($realPath);

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con el código que intentas usar? Qué error encuentras?

Comment: El problema es que no me deja separar la ruta por ejemplo obtener users de la ruta C:\xampp\htdocs\Dranix\vista\users\prs\registroCode.php

Comment: Ya lo arregle con $ruta = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $ruta = explode("/", $ruta);

Comment: @DragoDan considera publicar tu respuesta, para hacernos saber como lo solventaste, así mismo marcarla como aceptada y de paso llevarte unos votos positivos de reputación

Answer (score 0):

Ya que tu ruta es un String puedes utilizar la función interna de php llamada **explode**.

> Explode convierte las cadenas en un array separandolas por el primer string que se le pase como parámetro, el segundo parámetro que espera explode es tu cadena de texto (ruta).

```
$ruta = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Dranix\vista\users\prs\registroCode.php';
$rutaArr = explode('\\', $ruta);
echo $rutaArr[3];
```